# Cannot seem to initialize a spark context (pyspark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, ubuntu, pyspark

I have included the entire error below, when I try to run `sc = SparkContext(appName="exampleName")`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/sharan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/home/sharan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 188, in _do_init
    self._javaAccumulator = self._jvm.PythonAccumulatorV2(host, port)
  File "/home/sharan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1525, in __call__
    answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
  File "/home/sharan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 332, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name, value))
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2([class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Integer]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:179)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:196)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:237)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have no idea on how to debug this. Are there any logs that I  can access? Am I missing a specific package that I should be having on my ubuntu computer?

Comment: Are you running this from `pyspark` command line ? If so, then you can not do that because when you enter in a pyspark shell , a sparkcontext is initialized with its default values and spark does not allow to run multiple `sparkcontext` for a single driver.

Comment: @MdShihabUddin I'm running this as a python3 program

Comment: Seems like you've mixed incompatible versions of Java and Python code. This usually happens when you install `pyspark` with `pip` (or similar tool) independent of the actual Spark installation, or you have multiple Spark versions, and incorrectly configured Python search path or `SPARK_HOME`.

Comment: Here is a similar issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52646868/using-pyspark-on-windows-not-working-py4j

Answer (score 1):

This is due to pyspark version is different from spark version. If you have installed spark version 2.4.7 then use pyspark version 2.4.7 as well.

To get the spark version, check it on spark UI or use anyone of the following commands

`spark-submit --version`
or
`spark-shell --version`
or
`spark-sql --version`

To install the specific version of pyspark use the following command

`pip install pyspark==2.4.7`